# Custom newsbsite.aspx and custom webtmplates (sharePoint)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created new aspx file within a module which I am going to use it as instead of newsbsite.aspx for create workspaces. I have deployed it and I can browse to it via my custom action link (site settings).
I have my own webtemplates. 
What I want to do is using mynewsbsite.aspx to show only my webtemplates (not others) and implement permision inheritance and all other staff you can find in the original newsbsite.aspx. but I cann't.
is there anybody who can help me with this problem? thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SPWeb.GetAvailableWebTemplates Method (UInt32)`  to get all the templates and filter out the out of the box ones.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebtemplate(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Hi Madhur and thanks for your answer, 
How can I customize the newsbsite.aspx itself so that it shows only some of the out of the box templates no all of them.? thank you again.

Comment: You can go to Site Settings. There is a link using which you can filter the templates to display. I do not exactly remember the name of the link.